# when trying to remove, "xxx" is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: entity-framework

When I try to remove, using entity framework i have the following error:

> "The property 'User_ID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified."

Here is my code:

```
var rowToRemove = context.UD_User_Role.Where(w => w.User_ID == userId).ToList();
    context.UD_User_Role.RemoveRange(rowToRemove);
```

and here is my table's design:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632627/the-property-name-is-part-of-the-objects-key-information-and-cannot-be-modifi

Comment: thank you very much